# Hide 'Downloadable' and 'Virtual' checkbox options from Woocommerce Variations?

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying hide / unset the 'Downloadable' and 'Virtual' checkbox options from Woocommerce entirely. I have managed to unset them everywhere EXCEPT in the Woocommerce Variations Panel here:

[image: Woocommerce variations checkbox's - Downloadable and Virtual]

Looking in the Woocommerce plugin files I can see an action hook called 'woocommerce_variation_options' which seems to spit out the options for these checkboxes. I can obviously do a "dirty" injection of CSS here but whats the correct method to unset these checkboxes?

I am looking for something like this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_variation_options', 'my_customize_variation_fields_func', 10, 3 );
function my_customize_variation_fields_func( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ){  
// Remove / Unset "Virtual" checkbox
// Remove / Unset "Downloadable" checkbox
}
```

I have tried using `unset( $variation[ 'virtual' ] );` here but does not work? Any help / advice appreciated :-)

Comment: You'll need to check with WooCommerce support. Third-party plugins are [off topic](/help/on-topic) here.

Comment: @PatJ Thanks for the heads up! Doh I didn't realise.

Comment: The hint, often ignored, is in the 'woocommerce off-topic' tag that you used. Just saying for anyone that is lurking....

Comment: So I assume this has been considered 'off-topic' in more recent times? (As I see many older topics containing woo issues).